# MapHttpRoute in MVC WEB API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, routes

i want call delete method with its code.like 'api/vouchertype/JV0031'.
but id section only support integer. im add a route.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithCode", "Api/{controller}/{code}", new { code = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

and change method accordingly.

```
[HttpDelete]
public HttpResponseMessage Delete(String code)
{
       ....
}
```

but it not worked. How can i fix it ?

Comment: do you have any other routes in your application? ordering of routes is important and so wondering if you have any other route before the one mentioned in your post.

Comment: also what does not work...are you seeing  a 404 response? if yes, do you see any message in the body of this response?

Answer (score 0):

The request might not be processed by the UrlRoutingModule. Try adding this to your web.config, making this module to handle all process requests:

```
<modules>
  ...
  <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
  <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
  ...
</modules>
```